# Making tooltip position relative to windows size with AngularJS UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the position of a tooltip (based on the AngularJS Bootstrap UI) depending on the screen resolution, basically to have the first on mobile, and the second one on the rest (min-width ≥ 768px):

```
tooltip-placement="top"


tooltip-placement="left"
```

I've found a solution using jQuery (the next piece of code) but I wouldn't know how to implement it in Angular.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  var pos = ($(window).width() < 768) ? 'left' : 'top';
  $("#myDiv").tooltip({'placement': pos});
}).trigger('resize');
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a function in your scope for determining the tooltip placement. For example:

```
$scope.getTooltipPlacement = function () {
    return ($(window).width() < 768) ? 'left' : 'top';
};
```

Then on the element where you want the tooltip, you can call this function in the `tooltip-placement` attribute:

```
<a href="#" tooltip="My awesome tooltip" tooltip-placement="{{getTooltipPlacement()}}">Link</a>
```

Comment: This solution won't handle a resize event as the OP's jQuery snippet does. It's not clear whether that is a necessity though, as he only mentions his concern about mobile vs the rest.

Comment: @marck, that is true. I'd wager that in 99% of cases, that wouldn't be a concern since most tooltips appear/disappear on hover, and if you're resizing the browser window, then you're either (a) using the mouse to do it, in which case the tooltip would disappear anyway, or (b) if you're using the keyboard, whatever element you were hovering over wouldn't be in the same place since the window has probably moved. But if you have a tooltip where the trigger is something other than hover, then this would require something a bit more involved.